# How to solve these trigonometric functions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The functions that I need to solve are

1) $A\sin x + B \sin x \cos x + C \cos x=0$

and

2) $A\sin x + B \sin x \cos x + C \cos x+D=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Express $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in terms of $t=\tan (\frac{x}{2})$

$$\sin(x) = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}\text{ and }\cos(x) = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}$$

Comment: How I can do this?

Comment: $\sin x= 2 \sin x/2 \cos x/2$ and $\cos x= 1- 2\sin^2x/2$ then what?